# Check the number of arguments in a java program

Tags: java, exception, terminal, command-line-arguments

I have a java program that has two integers as input and has to do all four mathematical operations.

Meanwhile, I run my Java programs via terminal so the two integers are passed on as arguments. However, whenever I try to check the validity of the arguments passed I get a message saying:

(For example, if I ran: Java Example --> without any arguments I get the following message)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Example.main(Example.java:38)
```

My code is the following:

```
public class Example {
    public void Sum(int a, int b) {
        int sum = a + b;
        System.out.println("The sum:" + sum);
    }

    public void Sub(int a, int b) {
        int sub = a - b;
        System.out.println("The subtraction is:" + sub);
    }

    public void Mul(int a, int b) {
        int mul = a * b;
        System.out.println("The multiplication is:" + mul);
    }

    public void Div(int a, int b) {
        try {
            int div = a / b;
            System.out.println("The division is:" + div);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("You can't divide a number by 0");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example c = new Example();
        int count = args.length;
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        if (count == 0 || count > 2 || count == 1) {
            System.out.println("Not valid number of arguments try again. You entered " + count + " arguments");
        } else {
            c.Sum(x, y);
            c.Sub(x, y);
            c.Mul(x, y);
            c.Div(x, y);
            System.out.println("Arguments:" + count);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

What I write on the terminal is: e.g. Java Example 2 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the size of `args[]` is equal to `2` before trying to access `args[0]` and `args[1]`. Change `main` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example c = new Example();
    int count = args.length;
    if (count == 2) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        c.Sum(x, y);
        c.Sub(x, y);
        c.Mul(x, y);
        c.Div(x, y);
        System.out.println("Arguments:" + count);
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not valid number of arguments try again. You entered " + count + " arguments");
    }
}
```

On a side note, you should follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the names of the functions should be `sum`, `sub`, `mul`, `div` instead of `Sum`, `Sub`, `Mul`, `Div`.

Comment: Call it like `java Example 10 20`. Note that `10` and `20` will be treated as `args[0]` and `args[1]` respectively in your program. Feel free to comment in case of any issue/doubt.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now, it was my mistake :)